# ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49) when configuring Pass-Trough authentication with SASL in OpenLDAP with AD

Tags: authentication, active-directory, ldap, openldap, sasl

I'm using ubuntu 14.04 and OpenLDAP-2.4.40. I have synchronized Active Directory users in OpenLDAP using http://lsc-project.org/wiki/documentation/start utility. 
Now I want to do the authentications on the OpenLDAP part and will use the AD password using Pass-Trough authentication with SASL.

To do this I have followed this blog http://ltb-project.org/wiki/documentation/general/sasl_delegation 
After performing all the steps mentioned in this blog, I have fired the below command in command line to fetch user details:

> ldapsearch -x -H ldap://ldap.example.com -D uid=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=example,DC=com -w password -b CN=Users,DC=example,DC=com

but after that I am getting the result as '**ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)**'

even though credentials are correct.

Comment: Why don't you use Kerberos?

Comment: Is there any article or blog which shows step by step approach to use Kerberos for the above scenario?

Comment: This is for serverfault or superuser, not here.